# Loading jQuery plugin RhinoSlider content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery plugin `RhinoSlider` and have it working ok, however I want to load the content via AJAX to speed up the page load times. According to their site you need to change the call a little as per: http://rhinoslider.com/tricks/get-the-content-of-the-slider-via-ajax/

The default call is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // store the jquery object
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    $.get('content-of-slider.php', function(data){
        $slider.append(data).rhinoslider();
    });
});
```

That works fine, however I still need to include my options, I tried the below but it didn't work..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // store the jquery object
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    $.get('content-of-slider.php', function(data){
        $slider.append(data).rhinoslider(
            showTime: 6000,
            effectTime: 2500,
            autoPlay: true,
            showBullets: 'always',
            showControls: 'never',
            slidePrevDirection: 'toRight',
            slideNextDirection: 'toLeft'            
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Split the append and rhinoslider into 2 different calls

Comment: @Archer Could you please explain how to do that? I'm not a big JS version and the two things I tried didn't work.

Comment: @Archer Scratch that... just noticed that the code above was missing some curly braces, added that and it worked.

Comment: So obvious when you know!  Shame on both of us for missing that.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was missing the curly braces after the `rhinoslider(` portion; I added them as below and it now works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // store the jquery object
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    $.get('content-of-slider.php', function(data){
        $slider.append(data).rhinoslider({
            showTime: 6000,
            effectTime: 2500,
            autoPlay: false,
            showBullets: 'always',
            showControls: 'never',
            slidePrevDirection: 'toRight',
            slideNextDirection: 'toLeft'
        });
    });        
});
```